# jQuery - Dynamically adding numbers 1 - 'n' based on a given value

Tags: jquery, html, append, integer

Okay, Uber Noob back on the questions!

Context: Building a Timeline, not date specific

Problem: Adding numbers to HTML output via jquery

Have not started attacking the problem ( not expecting a full and easy answer ) so I am really looking for a starter. Thanks in advance.

```
    var dragger = $j('div.dragger');

    var totaldays = $j(dragger).width() / 245;
    var totaldaysround = Math.ceil(totaldays);
    var listdays = $j('span.totaldays').append('Estimated period of ' + totaldaysround + ' Days')

    // Total days echoed out in html tags

    var html = [];

    for (i = 0; i < totaldaysround; i++) {
        html.push('<span class="fldi day">Day</span>'); //just need to pipe in some numbers here
    }

    $j('span.days').append(html.join(''))
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: Sorry, once I have found total days as a number I now need to echo <span>Day 1</span><span>Day 2</span> etc.
I have got as far as echoing out <span>Day</span> x Total Days. Just need to add the numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should it be as simple as this ?

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    html.push('<span class="fldi day">Day ' + i + ' </span>');
}
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/n5rCU/

Answer (score 1):

Try with string concatenation:

```
for (i = 0; i < totaldaysround; i++) {
    html.push('<span class="fldi day">Day ' + i + '</span>');
}
```